# Running Visual Studio with a ASP .NET application, but where can I change the validation language in the website?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, translation

I'm running an ASP .NET application with individual authentication on the visual studio. When I check with the validation, the error sentences are showen in Chinese. I check the controller, viewer and some JS file. I couldn't find any Chinese words. I want these error sentences to be English.

Is this because my computer system or chrome version are Chinese? Where can I change the language?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Look at this first...**

In Visual Studio
Click Tools->Options->Environment->Internations Settings->Language.

[image: Internationl Settings]

**Look at this second...**

In Windows Settings (Windows + I) select Time and language and click language.

**Finally...**

Open Chrome->Settings->advanced->
Select the three dots next to preferred language.

> Uncheck Offer to translate pages in this language